# Get info using table Joins with 2 MySQL tables and DISTINCT

Tags: php, mysql, database, inner-join

I have two tables: the **'bidders'** and **'solditems'** tables.

The solditems table has 2 columns I need to use: *buyerid* and *paidstatus*.
In the bidders table, I want to get the info from columns: *bidnum*, *bidfname*, *bidlname*, *bidphnum*.  (the 'buyerid' values in sold items corresponds with 'bidnum' in bidders)

I'm trying to get unique buyer numbers from the solditems table with *paidstatus* marked as *unpaid*, and then get those buyers' info (fname, lname, and phnum) from the bidders table.

---

This is what I have right now:

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT(i.buyerid), 
      b.bidfname, 
      b.bidlname, 
      b.bidphnum 
FROM 'solditems' AS i 
INNER JOIN 'bidders' AS b ON i.buyerid = b.bidnum 
WHERE i.paidstatus='unpaid' 
ORDER BY i.buyerid ASC
```

If I use that in phpmyadmin sql section to test it, I get an error that says:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''solditems' AS i INNER JOIN 'bidders' AS b ON i.buyerid = b.bidnum WHERE i.paids' at line 1

I've never done any joins before but I just can't seem to get this working.

Comment: You are using '. You need to use ` for your columns.  e.g. \`solditems\`

Comment: ok let me give that a try, Matt

Comment: It worked thank you so much!  At least I got most of it right.

Comment: No worries Mort :) Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed ' to ` symbol for columns and ' to " for string values

```
SELECT 
     DISTINCT(i.buyerid), 
     b.bidfname, 
     b.bidlname, 
     b.bidphnum FROM `solditems` AS i 
INNER JOIN `bidders` AS b ON i.buyerid = b.bidnum 
WHERE i.paidstatus= "unpaid"
ORDER BY i.buyerid ASC
```

Comment: That works!  Thank you for your help.  I'll mark it as answered as soon as I can.